# Create angular material form via javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am trying to dynamically create a form using javascript and Angular material. The elements are created correctly, but the UI is not matching to the elements created in the HTML page.

Below is the code that generates the HTML markup for the elements:

```
$scope.elements = [{
    label: "username",
    value: "test"
}, {
    label: "password",
    value: "test"
}];

$scope.fields = [];
for (var f = 0; f < $scope.elements.length; f++) {
    var e = $scope.elements[f];
    var label = "<label>" + e.label + ": * </label>";
    var input = "<input id='test_" + f + "' value='" + e.value + "'/>";
    var tmp = label.concat(input);
    $scope.fields.push($sce.trustAsHtml(tmp));
}
```

I bind the `$scope.fields` to HTML using `ng-bind-html`.

```
 <md-input-container ng-repeat="field in fields" ng-bind-html="field" >
 </md-input-container>
```

Is there anything that I am missing or should add in order to have the same UI view as generated by static HTML.

Here's a JSFiddle link to the same which reproduces the above mentioned behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/fxwmda5w/6/

Comment: As I understand it, angular-material does some up-front work when the page loads to make those directive display correctly. Since you're adding them in the javascript(after page load), they aren't being rendered. 

What is your use case for this? Depending on what you're trying to do, ng-if might be a better choice

Comment: @pauljerman My use case is, the server sends me a list of input fields with their properties (input type, value) to display (can be 2, can be 10). So all I am trying to do is, display them accordingly.

Comment: In that case, I would instead use ng-repeat and dynamically fill in the input info. Maybe something like this would work: https://codepen.io/standard/pen/YePjZG

Comment: As you're using angular, use angular. The whole js code you have here is a simple `ng-repeat`, no need to strangely create elements as strings, then use `trustAsHtml` only to make things worse